# How do I compute the length of the following curve?

Tags: curves

I have the following problem.
I need to compute the length of the curve given by

> $z^2=2x,3y=xz$ between $(0,0,0)$ and $(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{6},1)$

I first want to find my curve, so geometrically I could draw it with geogebra but I can't see how to find my curve. Could maybe someone give me a hint?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Use the fact that $x=\frac{z^2}2$ and that $y=\frac{xz}3=\frac{z^3}6$.

Comment: oh nooo, I made the same computations but I somehow doesn't see that one can define $\phi:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ where $\phi(z)=(\frac{z^2}{2},\frac{z^3}{6},z)$ right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Parametrize your curve $\vec{r}(t) = (x(t), y(t), z(t))$, and then compute the arc-length integral of the curve:

$$
\int_{t_{1}}^{t_{2}} |\vec{r}'(t)| dt
$$

Hint: Define $y$, $z$ in terms of $x \in [0, 1/2]$

Comment: Now that I see Jose's Hint, maybe you should try his substitution first. It may require less work.